# How can I check the folders in a repository through svn

Tags: c, svn

I have a repository. I don't want to checkout the whole repository but just one folder inside it. I don't remember the folder names, so I want to see them. Is there a command in svn which can show all the folder names in the root directory of the repository.

Comment: This is not a specific algorithmic/programming question. Please consider posting it to programmers.stackexchange.com.

Comment: @H2CO3 this is a question about "*software tools commonly used by programmers*", so I disagree.

Comment: Why don't you read the documentation? It took me 1 minute to find the command: http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn-book.html#svn.ref.svn.c.list

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried `svn ls http://repo.url/here`?